# Kernel of the action of GL(V) on exterior square of V

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I wonder whether anyone knows a reference for the following result? I can give a shortish proof, but would prefer to cite the literature if possible.

**Theorem** Let $V=F^n$ be an $n$-dimensional $F$-space where $F$ is a field.
The action of ${\rm GL}(V)$ on $\Lambda^2(V)$ induces a homomorphism
$\phi_n\colon{\rm GL}_n(F)\to{\rm GL}_d(F)$ of matrix groups where $d=\binom{n}{2}$.
The kernel of $\phi_n$ is ${\rm GL}_1(F)$ if $n=1$, ${\rm SL}_2(F)$ if $n=2$, and
$\langle -I_n\rangle$ if $n\ge3$.

I will give a proof if there is no easy reference and one is requested.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a reference for the exact result, but two possible short arguments. Maybe something like this is what you had in mind, so this might not answer your question. But in any case, this is too long for a comment.

**Proof 1:** there are not many normal subgroups of $GL_n(F)$ in general, so you can just check from this what the kernel has to be.

**Proof 2:** in $\wedge^2(V)$, for nonzero elements $v \wedge w = v' \wedge w'$ if and only if $\langle v,w \rangle = \langle v', w' \rangle$ in $V$. This is basically the fact that the Plücker map is injective, which has textbook references.

For $n = 2$ the map $\phi_n$ is the determinant map, so the result is clear.

Assume $n > 2$. If $g \in \operatorname{ker} \phi_n$, then $g$ leaves every $2$-dimensional subspace of $V$ invariant. This implies that every line $\langle v \rangle$ is invariant under $g$. Indeed, let $\{v,v',v''\}$ be a linearly independent set. Since $\langle v,v' \rangle$ and $\langle v,v'' \rangle$ are $g$-invariant, so is their intersection $\langle v \rangle$.

A linear map which leaves every line invariant must be a scalar, from which the result follows.

Comment: I proved a generalization rather like testaccount's Proof 2, namely: If $n=\dim(V)> k$ and $g\in{\rm GL}_n(F)$ acts trivially on the $k$th exterior power $\Lambda^k(V)$ of $V$, then $g$ is a scalar matrix. The key tool is Lemma 12.6 of Don Taylor's book The Geometry of The Classical Groups. One needs to modify Proof2 *mutatis mutandis*.

Comment: Yes I agree a similar argument works more generally. We could also argue that if $1 < k < n$, then every $(k-1)$-space can be written as the intersection of two $k$-spaces. So if every $k$-space is invariant, then every $(k-1)$-space is invariant - again reducing to the case where every line is invariant.